# why scrollbars horizontal of Gridview not working?

Tags: android

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >      


 <GridView
    android:id="@+id/galleryImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="6"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >
    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
myGV= (GridView) findViewById(R.id.galleryImage);
listImage = new profileAdapter(this, R.layout.layoutimage);
myGV.setAdapter(listImage);
```

I have set number columns by value of `listImage`

```
myGV.setNumColumns(listImage.getCount());
```

Why are horizontal scrollbars of Gridview not working?

Comment: you are not passing any data to adapter , do you have enough items to scroll?

Comment: if i add more item to listImage, items will scale small, it not display scroll.

Comment: Are you trying to implement a swipe type feature of a full screen image?

Comment: Instead of parent `LinearLayout` try `Horizontal Scrollview` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

Comment: I am trying to implement a Gridview display image the same Gallery

Comment: @Arju i had try , but it not working.

Comment: do you remove the linearlayout? only a gridview inside the horizontal scroll

Comment: if only a gridview inside the horizontal scroll. Result not display srollbar: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6vmp7cjxawrmptm/device-2014-02-07-124944.png

Answer (score 0):

Hello please use below xml code I have added HorizontalScrollView

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tool"
android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

     <GridView
        android:id="@+id/galleryImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="6">
      </GridView>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: please add android:layout_width="fill_parent" in  GridView